# Create CSV and force download of file

Tags: php, csv

I have this PHP code that selects data from a database and creates a CSV file.

Its working fine, but how can i force download of the CSV file once it has finished being created?

I have added the headers at the top of the page but its not download the file

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=calls.csv');

$filename = $SettingsCustomer["company"].'-CallsTariff'.'-'.date("YmdHis");

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/file_dump/price_tariffs/'.$filename.'.csv', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('Number', 'Description', 'Per Minute Cost'));

// loop over the rows, outputting them
$cost=0;
$sql="SELECT * from call_costs where sequence < '50' ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    //check for custom costs
    $sql2="SELECT * from call_costs_custom where parent = '".$result["sequence"]."' AND customer_seq = '".$SettingsCustomer["sequence"]."' ";
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn);
    if(mysql_num_rows($rs2) > 0) {
        $result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

        $cost = $result2["cost"];
    } else {
        $cost = $result["retail"];
    }

    fputcsv($output, array($result["number"], $result["description"], $cost));
}
```

Comment: User can choose not download.

Comment: i want the created file to just download itself. the user clicks a link to download the file, it creates it then just downloads it so the user has already chosen to download it!

Comment: oh, you can create the file when user enter your page.Then downloads it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Charlie, this is a sample way to create and force download to csv file. Try to implement this in your code:

```
<?php

$filename = 'test';

$filepath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . $filename.'.csv';
$output = fopen($filepath, 'w+');

fputcsv($output, array("Number", "Description", "test"));
fputcsv($output, array("100", "testDescription", "10"));

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '.csv"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath)); 
echo readfile($filepath);
```

Comment: @charlie, i changed my answer.

Comment: Sorry @charlie, i changed my answer again.

Comment: just tried that, its now just echoing the whole file

Comment: @charlie, i change my answer again.

Comment: its still just echoing the file

Comment: Adding the `readfile()` function was the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please search the next time better. Thats everytime the same answer

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
```

text/csv is a display able content-type

Comment: that it returning Resource id #346

Comment: Ah thats the echo... Do you want to write it in a file at the same time?

Comment: its writing the file fine, i want to download the file as soon as its finished writing the created file

Comment: try echo file_get_contents( filename ); instead of your current echo.

Comment: dont forget to close your file before

Comment: ive added fclose($output); but its still not download the file. even after adding the file_get_contents

Comment: I make a new Answer... 1 moment... i forget that you miss some headers

Answer (score 0):

Well you need that at your end...

```
$file = '/file_dump/price_tariffs/'.$filename.'.csv';
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
```

You can remove the get_content_file

Comment: have you removed your first Content-Type header width text/csv?

Comment: good answer , @charlie make sure you're not echoing something before this part

Comment: i have put this on a single PHP page with no other code and its still just displaying it

Comment: interesting problem. can you try a other browser?